# Showing cloud animations on a website

Tags: clouds

I want to show cloud movements from satellite imagery.

How does sites like ZoomEarth.com make cloud animations? My understanding is:

1. They download images from satellite image providers.
2. Play those images sequentially.
   Is that correct?

How is the night time imagery handled?

Comment: I think this isn´t a question according to stack Earth Science. Try your luck at the stack overfolw page :D